# Will Chrome Bluetooth API works on windows XP and windows 7?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app

Will the following apis work on Windows XP and Windows 7? I tried it in Mac OS X, it works fine. But it didn't work on Windows XP with IOGEAR Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter (GBU521).

```
chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState(function(adapter) {
  console.log("Adapter " + adapter.address + ": " + adapter.name);
});

chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
    console.log("Inside getDevices");
  for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    updateDeviceName(devices[i]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Windows 8.1 in order to use BLE capabilities.